# Fetching image from parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

Below is the code for getting imagefile from parse,
but it throws `NullPointerException`.

Please let me know what is wrong in this code.

ImgFile-->is the class name in parse
Img-->column name in ImgFile

```
    imgItem= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Log.d("after image creation", " null");


    ParseObject anotherApplication = new ParseObject("ImgFile");
    ParseFile applicantResume = (ParseFile)anotherApplication.get("Img");
    applicantResume.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
     @Override
        public void done(byte[] data, com.parse.ParseException e) {

         if (e == null)
         {
             Log.d("before image", " null");
             Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                     data.length);

             if (bmp != null)
             { imgItem.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                 // img.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 0);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             Log.e("paser after downloade", " null");
         }
        }
    });
```

LogCat error is :

```
            02-20 16:21:32.435    7666-        7666/com.dsstechnologies.janardanswami E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dsstechnologies.janardanswami/com.dsstechnologies.janardanswami.Allimg}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:756)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:572)
        at miui.dexspy.DexspyInstaller.main(DexspyInstaller.java:171)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.dsstechnologies.janardanswami.Allimg.onCreate(Allimg.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5135)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callActivityOnCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2182)
```

**Allimg.java**

```
        public class Allimg extends Activity {
        public ImageView imgItem;
       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.allimg);

    // Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "",
            "");

       imgItem= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       Log.d("after image creation", " null");


    ParseObject anotherApplication = new ParseObject("ImgFile");
    ParseFile applicantResume = (ParseFile)anotherApplication.get("Img");
    applicantResume.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
     @Override
        public void done(byte[] data, com.parse.ParseException e) {

         if (e == null)
         {
             Log.d("before image", " null");
             Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                     data.length);

             if (bmp != null)
             { imgItem.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                 // img.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 0);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             Log.e("paser after downloade", " null");
         }
        }
    });


}
```

}

Thanking you..

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: Your object maybe null. Post your logCat for proper answer.

Comment: 16:21:32.435    7666-7666/com.dsstechnologies.janardanswami E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dsstechnologies.janardanswami/com.dsstechnologies.janardanswami.Allimg}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)

Comment: The code seems right, can you post the whole class?